# Javascript: Passing arguments to an inner setTimeOut function?

Tags: javascript, arguments, settimeout

I have a thumbnail scroller where I want to trigger some action only when the mouse is hovered for 3 seconds on thumbnails. I have the following code but the inner setTimeOut function is not getting the arguments from the outer function--the `sourceURL` console output gets '`undefined`' error. But the '`hover`' function I do see correct `sourceURL` value. 
Thanks in advance!

```
   var tOut;
   $('img.thumb').hover(function(){
      var sourceURL = $(this).attr('src');
      var lat = $(this).attr('lat');
      var lng = $(this).attr('lng');
      tOut = setTimeout(function(sourceURL,lat,lng){
      console.log(sourceURL);//undefined
      map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat, lng), (init_mapzoom+2));
    },3000);
   },function(){
     clearTimeout(tOut);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. But what code?

Comment: No. The setTimeOut needs to get the arguments from the hover function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass the variables to the function. As the function is created in a scope where the variables exist, they are caught in the closure for the function so the function can use them even after the scope is gone:

```
var tOut;
$('img.thumb').hover(function(){
  var sourceURL = $(this).attr('src');
  var lat = $(this).attr('lat');
  var lng = $(this).attr('lng');
  tOut = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(sourceURL);
    map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat, lng), (init_mapzoom+2));
  },3000);
},function(){
  clearTimeout(tOut);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `function` given to `setTimeout` doesn't have to receive them as arguments.

By also being defined within the `.hover()` `function`, it will have `sourceURL`, etc. in scope.

```
$('img.thumb').hover(function(){
  var sourceURL = $(this).attr('src');
  // ..

  tOut = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(sourceURL);
    // ...
  }, 3000);
}, ...);
```

Using them again as named parameters will [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the `var`s, so only the parameters are accessible within that `function`.

Comment: Thanks! Would accept your Answer but Guffa's came first.